# mysql return multiple 0 columns when row is empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this complex query that isn't working the way I would like and I was hoping someone could help me out.

```
SELECT 
 `username`, 
 `amount`, 
 `receipt`, 
 DATE_FORMAT(amount.time, '%e-%m-%Y') as paymentDate,
 SUM(CASE WHEN `our_result` = 'Y' THEN `difficulty` END) AS `accepted`,
 SUM(CASE WHEN `our_result` = 'N' THEN `difficulty` END) AS `rejected` 
FROM `shares`
JOIN ( 
 SELECT 
  amount, 
  time, 
  wallet, 
  receipt 
 FROM 
  userPayments 
 ORDER BY time DESC ) 
AS amount 
ON amount.wallet = shares.username 
WHERE `our_result` in ('Y','N') 
AND shares.time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
GROUP BY `username`
```

My problem is, when  the userPayments table is empty, no results show at all. I would like the remaining information to return, even when the userPayments table is empty but can't figure out how to make it happen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using left joins rather than inner joins?

Comment: Your method of sorting in a subquery and then using columns in the outer query that are not in the `group by` is specifically documented in MySQL not to work.  It says that the values come from "indeterminate" rows.  You should change the structure of your query.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and suggestion. I removed the sort within the subquery. I appreciate your help but had to award the answer to @bestia since it was spot on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use LEFT OUTER JOIN (or LEFT JOIN), instead of JOIN

It means:

```
SELECT 
 `username`, 
 `amount`, 
 `receipt`, 
 DATE_FORMAT(amount.time, '%e-%m-%Y') as paymentDate,
 SUM(CASE WHEN `our_result` = 'Y' THEN `difficulty` END) AS `accepted`,
 SUM(CASE WHEN `our_result` = 'N' THEN `difficulty` END) AS `rejected` 
FROM `shares`
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
 SELECT 
  amount, 
  time, 
  wallet, 
  receipt 
 FROM 
  userPayments 
 ORDER BY time DESC ) 
AS amount 
ON amount.wallet = shares.username 
WHERE `our_result` in ('Y','N') 
AND shares.time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
GROUP BY `username`
```